# Разрешение доступа для разных пользователей

Tags: android, алгоритм, firebase

Допустим есть приложение, в котором зарегистрировалось 3 пользователя. Есть активити с тремя кнопками.  Пользователь заходит в приложение и может нажать только на одну свою кнопку ( для каждого пользователя своя кнопка) , а на другие кнопки нажать не может.
Подскажите как это реализовать . 
Приложение делаю через Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в обработку нажатия на кнопку добавить проверку на соответствие кнопки и пользователя. Если нажата "своя" кнопка - выполнять действие, подвешенное на кнопку. Если нажата "чужая" - ничего не делать.